# when update kernels do they close bugs?

Tags: kernel, security, linux-kernel

When I upgrade my kernel to latest stable one which is 3.12.2, **does it close all security bugs**?

How linux security bugs be closed? by installing newer kernel or how ??and who closes these bugs?

Answer (score 6):

- No software will ever be bugfree/free of security issues.
- A new Kernel will only fix the **known** security issues of the previous release (given that there was somebody willing to fix them)
- Security issues of individual applications need to be fixed in the applications itself
- No software security can ever provide full security, it always comes down to how the sysadmin/user configured and uses his system

The [changelog for the Kernel release 3.12.2](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ChangeLog-3.12.2) lists all changes (new features, fixes, …) of the given release.